# Solving algebraic problems without algebra using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How would you solve a problem of this type using Microsoft Excel?

```
A bat and ball cost a dollar and ten cents. 
The bat costs a dollar more than the ball. 
How much does the ball cost?
```

(The answer is that the bat costs $1.05 and the ball costs $0.05.)

[Source](http://gizmodo.com/5918045/why-smart-people-are-actually-dumb)

Comment: Why on earth would you use Excel for that?

Comment: Perhaps a more pertinent question is "Why would you work it out in MS Excel?"

Comment: @ Hans Lundmark, Why not?

Comment: @oshirowanen: Because it is relatively simple to work this out without excel

Comment: @Juan S, it may be simple without Excel.  Does that mean it can't be done with excel?  If not, that's fine, if it can be done, I would like to know how.

Comment: I'm reopening this... it seems like an odd (not-a-real) question but Kaze wrote a great answer about goal seek so with some editing I think it can be salvaged

Comment: I think it's a really good question-the specific example is easy, but the concept has quite a bit of potential for solving complex problems.  I often try and simplify examples to make sure they work before applying them to real-world complexities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way using Goal Seek:

Enter the formula for the price of a bat in one cell (`BALL_PRICE + 1.00`), and the total in another (`BALL_PRICE + BAT_PRICE`). In my example below, **A2** contains the formula for the price of a bat, and **C2** contains the total:

[image]

Open  **Data** > **What-If Analysis** > **Goal Seek** and set it up this way:

[image]

You should get this after clicking **OK**:

[image]

Comment: This is a nice, easy solution that doesn't require you to do the algebra by hand first (which was the best I could figure).

Answer (score 2):

Bat price      1

Ball price     0.1  (=1.1 - bat price)

Difference     0.9  (=bat price - ball price)

Error          0.1  (=1.0-difference)

Now use goal seek to set error to 0 by changing bat price.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hans said, there's no need for Excel here. Let *x* be the price of the bat and *y* be the price of the ball. Since the two together cost $1.10 we have (in cents) *x* + *y* = 110. Since the bat costs a dollar more than the ball, we have *x* = *y* + 100.

The second equation allows us to replace *x* in the first, so (*x*) + *y* = 110 becomes (*y* + 100) + *y* = 110 so we find 2_y_  + 100 = 110 and subtracting 100 from both sides gives 2y = 10 so *y* = 5 so the ball costs 5 cents and hence, since the two prices total 110 we find that the bat must cost 105.